# Setting onChange event for GPIO interface in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, events, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have Node.JS installed on my Raspberry Pi with [pi-gpio](https://npmjs.org/package/pi-gpio) installed giving me access to the gpio ports. I can read and write ok, but given the event driven nature of node.js, is it possible to set it up so that when a GPIO input changes and goes high, or low, or both (depending on setup), an event is fired?

Comment: I think this exact question was answered here: [Async raspberry pi gpio events in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440204/async-raspberry-pi-gpio-events-in-nodejs)